# RecyclerViews scrolling inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerViews positioned vertically, one above the other. I want them to scroll as one but what happens is a) the second recyclerView is hidden and b) if I change `NestedScrollView` height to match_parent then both are visible but the second one scrolls **below** the first.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:fillViewport="true" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in where you are setting up your recycler view

```
// In case you have not provided
final LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm );

// for scrolling 
recyclerView1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```